# How to remove the page numbers in the front matter only

Tags: pdftex, front-matter

I'm a LaTeX beginner, so be patient with me.

I want to add a blank page after the title page, without showing a page number.

I want to suppress page numbers in the front matter only.

I added `\thispagestyle{empty}`, but it doesn't give me the desired solution :(

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[width=4.375in, height=7.0in, top=1.0in, papersize={5.5in,8.5in}]{geometry}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tipa}

\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection\ #1}}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\bfseries\thepage}
\fancyhead[LO]{\bfseries\rightmark}
\fancyhead[RE]{\bfseries\leftmark}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\addtolength{\headheight}{0.5pt}
\setlength{\footskip}{0in}
\renewcommand{\footruleskip}{0pt}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
    \fancyhead{}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
}
%
%\parindent 0in
\parskip 0.05in
%
\begin{document}
    \frontmatter
    %
    \chapter*{\Huge \center New Metaphysics }
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    %{\hspace{0.25in} \includegraphics{./ru_sun.jpg} }
    \section*{\huge \center Suresh Emre}
    \newpage
    \subsection*{\center \normalsize Copyright \copyright 2009 by Author}
    \subsection*{\center \normalsize All rights reserved.}
    \subsection*{\center \normalsize ISBN \dots}
    \subsection*{\center \normalsize \dots Publications}
    %
    \chapter*{\center \normalsize ...}
    %
    \tableofcontents
    %
    \mainmatter
    %
    \chapter{Subjectivation and Objectivation}
    % your text here
    In human history no philosopher or sage explained the cosmic mystery and the spiritual reality more rationally than Shrii Shrii Anandamurti (1921-1990) \cite{baba_books} \cite{anandamitra}. His rational outlook is truly inspiring.
    %
    \chapter{Description of the Principle}
    % your text here
    %
    \chapter{Creation of Cosmos as Objectivation}
    % your text here
    %
    \chapter{More on Cosmic Subjectivation}
    % your text here
    %
    \chapter{More on Multiplicity}
    % your text here
    %
    \chapter{Curvature}
    % your text here
    %
    \chapter{Creation of the Physical Universe}
    % your text here
    %
    \chapter{An Example from the Later Stages}
    % your text here
    %
    \backmatter
    %
    \begin{thebibliography}{99}
        \bibitem{baba_books}
        Books of Shrii Shrii Anandamurti (Prabhat Ranjan Sarkar): \\
        http://shop.anandamarga.org/
        \bibitem{anandamitra}
        Avtk. Ananda Mitra Ac., \emph{The Spiritual Philosophy of Shrii Shrii Anandamurti: A Commentary on Ananda Sutram}, Ananda Marga Publications (1991) \\
        ISBN: 81-7252-119-7
    \end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

Comment: you don't show which class you are using.

Comment: I'm using the book class. \LoadClass[12pt,a4paper,twoside]{book}

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  You should be able to add `\pagestyle{empty}` immediately after `\frontmatter`.  It will be reset by `\mainmatter`.

Comment: Hi Barbara, this worked, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As soon as the document class was clearly identified as `book`, it became possible to offer a suggestion.

`book` subdivides the document content into three distinct parts: `\frontmatter`, `\mainmatter`, and `\backmatter`,  At each of these transitions, certain global changes are applied.  At `\mainmatter`, the format of page numbers is changed from \roman`to`\arabic`, and the counter is reset to 1.

Thus, declaring `\pagestyle{empty}` after `\frontmatter` is applied will be overridden safely at `\mainmatter`.